# Look for file if directory doesn't exist nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm moving an old site over from a box running apache to a new one running nginx.  The old site uses `.htaccess` rules that I'm finding hard to translate to nginx config syntax.

Specifically, if a request on the old site is made to `example.com/video` then, if there is no directory `video`, it loads `video.php` or `video.html` file instead.

Here are the `.htaccess` rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .? /index.html [L]
```

I tried the following in nginx with no luck (404):

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  example.org www.example.org;

        access_log /var/log/example.org/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/example.org/error.log;

        root   /var/www/vhosts/example.org/;

        index  index.html index.htm;

        location / {

                rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1\.php break;
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1\.html break;
                if (!-e $request_filename){
                        rewrite .? /index.html break;
                }
        }
        location /app {
                rewrite ^/app/? /join?p=getApp redirect;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `try_files` directive was made just for this scenario:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Your nginx config would then look like so:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.org www.example.org;

    access_log /var/log/example.org/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/example.org/error.log;

    root   /var/www/vhosts/example.org/;

    index  index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.php $uri.html;
    }

    location /app {
            rewrite ^/app/? /join?p=getApp redirect;
    }
```